# API response showing in console.log but not on react page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I ma trying to show part of an APi response but it keeps giving me undefined when i try to parse it.

I have tried doing 2 parts of the API response but neither work.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      head: 0,
      data: [],
      firstName: "Brad",
      lastName: "Marchand",
      err: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/api/player", {
        params: {
          firstName: this.state.firstName,
          lastName: this.state.lastName
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        //this.err = err;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>{this.state.data.players[0].player.firstName}</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

backend

```
 request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      signale.error(err);
    }
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    //var data = JSON.stringify(data.players);
    //var data = JSON.parse(data);

    signale.success(data);
    res.send(data);
  });
```

```
{ lastUpdatedOn: '2019-08-15T15:20:13.791Z',
[0]   players: [ { player: [Object], teamAsOfDate: [Object] } ],
[0]   references: { teamReferences: [ [Object] ], venueReferences: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Another expected response
[Another response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zIMR.png)

Trying to just output what i want from  the response but always get undefined past this.state.data

Comment: Do a `this.state.data.players[0].player.firstName` in your axios call and a `this.state.data` in your `render` method to make sure.

Comment: does this api works in postman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React setState() works asynchronously, which means there is a slight delay in setting the value in the state. You can passing in a callback to setState() which is called once the state is updated.

```
 this.setState({
     data: response.data
 }, () => { console.log(this.state.data); });
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you. Oddly I knew it was async but for some reason thought the component wouldn't load until it was complete.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that you are making an API call in componentDidMount and the response of the API will definitely come after the initial render, and in the initial render, `this.state.data.players[0].player.firstName` is undefined and it breaks your code. Add a conditional check before accessing the value. Also initialise `data` state as an object if its one

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      head: 0,
      data: {},
      firstName: "Brad",
      lastName: "Marchand",
      err: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/api/player", {
        params: {
          firstName: this.state.firstName,
          lastName: this.state.lastName
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        //this.err = err;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>{this.state.data.players && this.state.data.players[0].player.firstName}</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```